# Can't use fontawesome icons properly in component in angular

Tags: angular, frontend

```
<i class="fas far"
  [class.fa-star]= "isChecked"
  [class.fa-star]= "!isChecked"
  (click)="onClick()"
></i>
```

I am building this angular component where it displays solid star icon when it is clicked (`isChecked` value is true), and empty star when it isn't (`isChecked` value is false). But, I'm facing this issue as how to use `class.fa-star` because angular will be confused as to which `fa-star` to display (solid or hollow star because both have same name but different class of icons).

I tried doing "class. fas fa-star" but its giving me an error.

Answer (score 2):

```
<i class="fa" 
    [class.fa-star]="isChecked"
    [class.fa-star-o]="!isChecked"
    (click)="isChecked = !isChecked">
</i>
```

in your `component.ts`

```
isChecked: boolean = false;
```

here is your working code on stackblitz: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-14ebpj?file=src/index.html)

Comment: This isnt working :( one fa-star is from fas(solid) and one from far(star regular). the onClick() function is working fine and the problem lies in class.fa-star, now this confuses angular as to what star to display, solid or regular? i cant use 'class.fas fa-star'. please help

Comment: Import this at the head of your `index.html`. Just use the `fa` in your class. The `fa-star` is solid while `fa-star-o` is hallow.  See above code and check the stackblitz
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty sure what exact issue which you are facing. but if you want to multiple classes at the same time you can use `[ngClass]` attribute to achieve that like below

```
<i class="fa-star"
    [ngClass]="{'far class1 class2': isChecked, 'fas class3 class4': !isChecked}"
    (click)="isChecked = !isChecked">
</i>
```